# MySQL Issues on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: apache2, mysql

I've an Ubuntu Server 22.04 installed on VPS.

Then, I install a Apache + PHP and all works correctly at this moment:
Commands used:
`sudo apt-get install apache2 -y`
`sudo apt install mysql-server-8.0 -y`
`sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql -y`

I try check if any issue on MySQL Server, and this services appear all OK.
Tests dids for get my idea:
`Used mysql command and executed some queries like "CREATE DATABASE number1"` 
`Created a user + remote access, login with that user via SQLYog 13.2 and do some queries`

But, when an php website try use mysql, it returns de next error:

> *CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver*

What's wrong on my Apache, why Web Applications can't connect to MySQL?

Best regards

Comment: Silly question, but did you remember to restart Apache after installing PHP and subsequent packages? 

Answer (score -2):

Try to install `php-sqlite` (drive)

`sudo apt-get install phpX.Y-sqlite` (replace x.y with your current PHP version)
and after that restart apache's service.

`sudo service apache2 restart`